# xcode maven plugin install prebuilt

Tags: ios, xcode, maven

We are evaluating xcode-maven-plugin from http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/ for handling iOS library dependencies using maven. It looks really promising but we are using some prebuilt third party libs we don't have the source code from that we would like to also install in maven and resolve as maven dependencies but we don't know how to achieve that with the plugin.

We have already used the maven-android-plugin for Android to upload third party binaries and we manage to do that playing with the headerFilesDirectives and nativeLibrariesOutputDirectory parameters but we haven't found anything similar for the xcode plugin.

Does anyone know if it is possible to install prebuilt iOS libraries with the latest(1.14.0) xcode-maven-plugin version?.

We are new to Maven so maybe we are missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do not you use a [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/) instead? It's a dependency manager for Objective-C projects. It's like iOS equivalent of Maven.

Comment: Thanks Javier, that looks good and it has a way to use private repos and create pods for binary third party libs, I'd prefer to stick to Maven so we can manage the dependencies for all our platforns using the same system but I'll consider it as an option to deal with dependencies in iOS.